# Xamarin - How to attach file?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, attachment

I'm using xamarin.form PCL cross-platform having two project - android and iOS.

I want to attach file (any file) from google drive/i Cloud/drop box and save file in bytes in database

Please suggest me how can I attach and save in database

Comment: attach a file to what? Upload to what server? It is not clear where the file is going, and in what manner, just that it is coming from dropbox etc.

Comment: I make change in question. File will be save in database